# ActiveMQ "Classic" message grouping and auto-rebalancing consumers

Tags: spring, configuration, queue, activemq-classic

I have several apps that send to one queue. In my case I need to use message groups. Can I somehow re-balance when adding another consumer? Let's say I had 2 consumers and 50 messages were sent with 4 groups so 2 groups per consumer. Then the next two consumers are added, and I would like to re-balance so that the next consumers take over the processing of these 2 additive groups.

I'm using activemq-spring in version 5.12.1.

I tried looking for information in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html), but there is nothing specific.

Comment: Despite the lack of documentation it is possible to manually rebalance the consumers/groups using the `removeAllMessageGroups` as Matt pointed out. I added this information to the documentation. However, if you want to _automatically_ rebalance then I believe you'll need to use [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/). See [this documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/message-grouping.html#rebalancing-message-groups) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ 5.x can do this by clearing the Message Group cache on the queue via JMX operation. Performing this operation will rebalance consumers.

The JMX operation you want to rebalance all consumers:

```
removeAllMessageGroups
```

Note: You might need to upgrade, as 5.12.x is quite dated.

Comment: I added this information to [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html#adding-new-consumers) in the "Adding New Consumers" section.

Comment: BTW, is there a way to _automatically_ rebalance the groups when new consumers are added?